# infinite loop on consent screen login with google android ionic capacitor

Tags: authentication, ionic-framework, google-signin, capacitor

I recently created an application with ionic capacitor, in it I use login with google, but I have the following drawback, on some phones (very few) it does not log, it stays on the consent screen, and when they press allow, it shows a loading and returns to leave the consent screen, over and over again, as in an infinite cycle, the thing is that I cannot replicate this on any device or emulator, it has happened on android 8 and 5.1, I even downloaded an emulator with android 5.1 and still I am not able to replicate the error, 90% of the users do manage to enter.
I do not know much about android, however I was reviewing the official documentation and it is identical to the implementation of the plugin (except for the calls to javascript after finishing), I thought it could be the configuration in the console, but I do not think, since as I said in 90% of the devices it works fine.
I would really appreciate if anyone could give me at least an idea on how to replicate the error, or something like that.

this is the plugin in question, in case it is of any use

https://github.com/CodetrixStudio/CapacitorGoogleAuth

I do not share code because I am sure that the problem is not in javascript

these are the scopes i'm using "profile", "email"

Comment: hey, have you get any solution for this issue?

Comment: @VivekJain 
I did find a solution, but it was a long time ago, I think in my case it was to set this "forceCodeForRefreshToken" in  true, because in false need more permissions in the console, 
but it was so long ago that I'm not sure, try that and tell me